# Installed SQL Server 2014, but only the 2008 SQL engine is running?

Tags: sql-server

Folks,
I installed SQL Server Express 2014 on three of our servers, and on two have no problem.  On the third, I cannot add a new database and set the compatibility to 2014 (120).

I have done SELECT @@VERSION, and yes, it's the 2008 engine that's still running.  I don't understand why the 2014 engine isn't running.  All the same installed bits appear in this server as in one that's working properly.

The Services list shows just the 2008 Agent and Browser, none for the 2014 installation.

Weirdest is that the location where the 2014 service lives on the drive of the working server (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS) doesn't appear on the troubled server.  But then...where's my 2014 stuff *actually installed*?  (I've checked similar paths on other drives, and in the Program Files (x86) location.)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be able to help you quicker.

Comment: I would move this to the DBA site as suggested by @EricS